# Regex: don't match a word that is within another word

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I tell Regex to not match a word that is already within a word in Javascript.

For example the text:

```
brown and white sandy
```

I dont want to select the 'and' within 'sandy' only the **'and'** that is not within another word.

For some reason the following code does not work:

```
 correctedText = correctedText.replace(new RegExp('\band\b', 'g'), '/');
```

Comment: Because you have a typo. `new RegExp('\\band\\b', 'g')` or you could just type `/\band\b/g`.

Comment: Use a regex literal `correctedText.replace(/\band\b/g, '/');`

Comment: Ahh! Simple enough, thank you! that did the trick! :)